# jpa native query control entity(part 3)

Tags: java, mysql, jpa

- Retrieve company table
  *GetEntity.java*

  ```
  String table = "company";
  String q = "select * from " +table;

  Query query = em.createNativeQuery(q, Company.class);
  List<Company> list = query.getResultList();
  ...
  ```
- Retrieve staff table
  *GetEntity.java*

  ```
  String table = "staff";
  String q = "select * from " +table;

  Query query = em.createNativeQuery(q, Staff.class);
  List<Staff> list = query.getResultList();
  ...
  ```
- My questions is how do I control the ? from the following:

  ```
  em.createNativeQuery(q, ?);
  List<?> list = q.getResultList();
  ```

  Any ideas or suggestion?

Comment: Control the "?" ?  This is an entity loaded by the EMF, usually from annotations in the concrete class.  Look at the EMF metadata http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManagerFactory.html#getMetamodel%28%29  this can be used to enumerate the concrete entity classes available ?  Please reword your question if I have misunderstood.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to pass the Class entityClass as an argument to your find method and then you can try and derive table name from entityClass by using reflection and use the entityClass as the type argument to your createNativeQuery method.

Hope this helps!